# Line from Origin to Nodes at circles centers

Tags: nodes, draw, tikz-node, node-connections

I want to produce a figure like this:

[image]
 with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10.75cm];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4.2cm];

\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
 \draw[fill=gray!20,thick] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm] circle [radius=6cm];
\end{scope}



\draw [fill=white] node (x25) {} (6.042,1.053) circle [radius=1.05cm];



\draw [fill=white] (0.363,7.83) circle [radius=1.05cm] node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill=black,pos=0.5] (x26) {};




\draw [fill=white] (-6.04,-1.069) circle [radius=1.05cm] node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill=black,pos=0.5] (x27) {};




\draw [fill=white] (-0.35,-7.821) circle [radius=1.05cm] node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill=black,pos=0.5] (x28) {};




\draw (0,0) -- (x25) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_1$};
\draw (0,0) -- (x26) node[pos=0.4,fill=white,circle] {$r_2$};
\draw (0,0) -- (x27) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_3$};
\draw (0,0) -- (x28) node[pos=0.4,fill=white,circle] {$r_4$};


\draw (0,0) -- ++(3.5,0);

\draw[->] (0:2.5cm) arc (0:9.893:2.5cm) node[pos=0.5,label={0:$\varphi_1$}] {};
\draw[->] (0:2.0cm) arc (0:87.347:2.0cm) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$\varphi_2$};
\draw[->] (0:1.5cm) arc (0:190.0:1.5cm) node[pos=0.6,fill=white,circle] {$\varphi_3$};
\draw[->] (0:1cm) arc (0:267.37:1cm) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$\varphi_4$};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

however I obtain only this:

[image]

The lines from the origin to the nodes `x25` to `x28` do not appear.
Any help?

Comment: Nice question (+1). It seems that you are here for quite some time and asked quite a few nice questions as well. So, before asking a new question, if you find the answers to your old questions useful, consider accepting them.

Comment: I have already accepted my old questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first node `(x25)` is placed at the origin `(0,0)` since you did not specify where it should be.
By moving its definition after the coordinate `(6.042,1.053)` it moves to where you want it to be.
I simply commented on the other parts of your useless code. But I didn't simplify your code.

### Update: more explanations

Following @JohnKormylo's comment, I looked for the cause of this error and unless I'm mistaken, it's because the path is reduced to a **single point**, instead of two: the current point and the previous point.

Here is your reduced code to a minimum:

```
\draw [fill=white] (0.363,7.83) circle [radius=1.05cm] node[pos=0.5] (x26) {};
```

Indeed, I am quoting page 151 of the manual:

> \path ... circle[< *options* >] ...; This command adds a circle to the
>   current path where the center of the circle is the current point by
>   default, but you can use the at option to change this. The **new current**
>   point of the path will be (typically just remain) the **center of the
>   circle**.

And the page 235 of the manual:

> /tikz/pos=< *fraction* > (no default) When this option is given, the node is
>   not anchored on the last coordinate. Rather, it is anchored on some
>   point on the line from the **previous** coordinate to the **current** point.

[image: nodes]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10.75cm]node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=black]{}; 
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4.2cm];

\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
 \draw[fill=gray!20,thick] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm] circle [radius=6cm];
\end{scope}

\draw [fill=white] (6.042,1.053) circle [radius=1.05cm]node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=black] (x25) {} ;
\draw [fill=white] (0.363,7.83) circle [radius=1.05cm] 
[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill=black
%,pos=0.5
] (x26) {};
\draw [fill=white] (-6.04,-1.069) circle [radius=1.05cm] node
[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill=black
%,pos=0.5
]
 (x27) {};
\draw [fill=white] (-0.35,-7.821) circle [radius=1.05cm] node
[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill=black
%,pos=0.5
] 
(x28) {};

\draw (0,0) -- (x25) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_1$};
\draw (0,0) -- (x26) node[pos=0.4,fill=white,circle] {$r_2$};
\draw (0,0) -- (x27) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_3$};
\draw (0,0) -- (x28) node[pos=0.4,fill=white,circle] {$r_4$};

\draw (0,0) -- ++(3.5,0);

\draw[->] (0:2.5cm) arc (0:9.893:2.5cm) node[pos=0.5,label={0:$\varphi_1$}] {};
\draw[->] (0:2.0cm) arc (0:87.347:2.0cm) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$\varphi_2$};
\draw[->] (0:1.5cm) arc (0:190.0:1.5cm) node[pos=0.6,fill=white,circle] {$\varphi_3$};
\draw[->] (0:1cm) arc (0:267.37:1cm) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$\varphi_4$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting that adding [pos=0.5] causes so much trouble.  I guess it was trying to place it halfway around a circle with no beginning and no end..

Comment: @JohnKormylo I found this error strange and I looked for its cause, it seems to me that I have identified it. I updated my answer.

Comment: So, merely halfway along a line with no beginning (or no end, depending on semantics). ;-)